# Program not running as intended

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program that will add inputs until the total equals 100+ OR the user inputs 5 numbers. I'm also attempting to add a highest run to it that keeps track of the highest input. Currently it continues to run after 5 inputs when it's less than 100 total and my highest run doesn't work. How would I fix this?(I'm new to Java if you can tell)

```java
import java.io.*;

public class HighScoreTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // input streams.
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);   

        // constant declarations
        final Integer MAX = 100; 
        final Integer MAX_NUMBER = 4;

        // variable declarations
        String   sName;
        Integer  currentTotal;
        Integer  currentNumber;
        Integer  numbersInputed = 0;
        Integer  count;
        Integer  maxRunToDate = 0;
        // we catch exceptions if some are thrown.
        // an exception would be entering a string when a number is expected
        try {
              System.out.println("What is your name?");  

              // reading string from the stream
              sName = reader.readLine();  
              currentTotal = 0;

              for(count = 0; count < MAX_NUMBER; count++) {
                  numbersInputed += count;
              }

              do {
                  System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                  currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                  currentTotal = currentTotal + currentNumber;
              }while(currentTotal < MAX || numbersInputed == MAX_NUMBER);

              if (maxRunToDate < currentTotal) {
                  maxRunToDate = currentTotal;
              }

              System.out.println(sName +", the total for this run is "+ currentTotal);
              System.out.println("The highest run is "+ maxRunToDate);

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading from user");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Shorten your program as much as you can while still reproducing the problem. Don't ask us to debug the whole program for you. Once you've shortened it then you'll probably see the problem, or can ask again.

Comment: If you want the user to input 5 numbers, why is `MAX_NUMBER` set to 4?

Answer (score 1):

Some help to get you going:

```
currentRun = currentRun + currentNumber;
```

Simply doesn't make sense!

I assume that currentRun should count the **number of runs** so far. So that you can stop after the 5th round.

Thus: you should just increment that counter by for each round.

In other words: try to **separate** things. Step back and consider what kind of information you want to "track" and how many variables you really need to do that.

And please understand: we will not solve your assignment for you. If at all, there will be some guidance on how to make progress. But don't expect us to figure **all** the bugs in your code and resolve them for you.

Comment: His `numbersInputed ` makes no sense aswell, basically the whole code is strange.

Comment: I named that variable weirdly, I mean't    currentTotal as in the total accumulated to that point. So, that line would update the    currentTotal by adding the number that the user just inputed to the total at that point. numberInputed is the variable to add up how many inputs.

Comment: @Lummers What you *meant* to do doesn't matter. The computer (and us), we only know about the **code** you wrote. And as Murat says, your code looks weird in various ways. I pointed out **one** obvious problem with your code to get you going ...

Answer (score 0):

There is several things that you need to know:

First, avoid wrap classes like `Integer` unless you intend to use it together with the `Colection` FrameWork or even Streams. If your problem is the fact that the output of the parsing is the `Integer` class, don't worry, for it will auto unbox. Something like this:

```java
int currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()); //Auto Unboxing
```

Second, why do you even have the for loop in the beginning? Remove it. If you want to initialize the `numbersInputed` variable just do it.

And third, if you whant to increment or decrement, you can just use `++` or `--

And check the Oracle Tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)